# How to implement a List<T> property in a C# class?

Tags: c#, list, properties

I have the code below:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

and the Blog class itself:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
}
```

I instantiate the list property in Program class (main method) by this way:

```
lBlog.Add(new Blog { Id = 1, Title = "War & Peace", PublicationDate = new DateTime(2020, 02, 23) });
```

So far - good. But, when I'm trying to add it to author object it's empty

```
author.Blogs.AddRange(lBlog);
```

Comment: Do you mean, that `Blogs` collection is empty?

Comment: lBlog is a list. I've initialized it by this way:

Comment: use `author.Blogs = IBlog` instead

Comment: LBlog list is good . It has the detailes i fill in.
But when i'm trying to add it to Author's object , the message is " ... not set to an instance object" . What is the problem.

Comment: You haven't instantiated the list object - you need to do that inline or in the constructor. The list isn't a list yet - it's `null`

Comment: for more clarifications please add complete code to question, it is not clear what you want?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize `Blogs` list in `Author` class constructor

```cs
public class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        Blogs = new List<Blog>();
    } 

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Or use property initializer for that (it's available from C# 6). In this case make sense to make a property `readonly` (to prevent overwriting a property from outside)

```cs
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Blog> Blogs { get; } = new List<Blog>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } = new List<Blog>();
    }
```